# Throttling/Adjusting Bandwidth in Conjunction with Bitmonerod

Tags: monerod-commands, bandwidth

When running bitmonerod and using the following bitmonerod bandwidth parameters, is the rate measured in bits or bytes?

- `limit_up` Used within bitmonerod while running.
- `limit_down` Used within bitmonerod while running.
- `--limit-rate-up`  Command line argument for launching bitmonerod.
- `--limit-rate-down` Command line argument for launching bitmonerod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these are measured in kB (1024 bytes). See [src/p2p/net_node.inl](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/blob/master/src/p2p/net_node.inl), in set_rate_up_limit.

The defaults are 2048 kB/s upload, and 8192 kB/s download. If those are near or above your connection's capabilities, you may want to lower them to a bit lower, to keep some QoS. Similarly if you have a fast connection, you might want to increase them.

Answer (score 2):

The rate is measured is kilo**Bytes** per second.